# Получить значение data-атрибута и этим значением заменить содержание span-элемента

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, map

Есть несколько span элементов с data-атрибутом data-caption. Моя задача получить значение этого атрибута и заменить им значение самого span.

```js
let dataCaptions = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.caption[data-caption]'), function(el) {return el.dataset.caption;});
let captions = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.caption'), function(el) {return el.textContent;});
captions = dataCaptions;
```

```html
<div class="captions">
  <span class="caption" data-caption="North">Север</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="South">Юг</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="East">Восток</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="West">Запад</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в принципе практически все сделали сами, но достаточно будет один раз получить все элементы с `.caption` и там же поменять текст контент. Ну и заменил `map` на `forEach` так как новый массив Вам вроде как не нужен.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.caption'), (el) => {
  el.textContent = el.dataset.caption;
});
```

```html
<div class="captions">
  <span class="caption" data-caption="North">Север</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="South">Юг</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="East">Восток</span>
  <span class="caption" data-caption="West">Запад</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То что нужно!